# using the registration app in django python

Tags: django, django-registration

I have followed the http://lightbird.net/dbe/forum3.html#user-registration tutorial to use the registration application in django.
I assume that the registration application works because I get the register user in the database of the app, The problem is that I cant log in with the user I guess I need to confirm the registration by email. How do I resolve this problem just for the developing purposes.
My register form is at localhost/accounts/register/ and my login form is at
localhost/accounts/login/
when I try to log in nothing happens I stay on the same screen.

Comment: What the system said when you try to login?

Comment: I found the solution in this tutorial, http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2011/01/14/setting-up-django-registration/ it seam tat you can start email server on your localhost and get the print out of the activation url for the account and you just need to add this url to the browser to activate the account.

Comment: ah the email config, good ...

Comment: any way, is there a option after a user login, to get the users data. From what I can see, I can only check if a user is logged in or not by the request.user.is_authenticated(), but how can I get other details from a logged in user like username or email? Thanks

Comment: form.cleaned_data('username')